# Could I represent a two dimensional reciprocal lattice by just one integer index?

Tags: solid-state-physics, vectors, crystals, linear-algebra

By considering the following reciprocal lattice vector
$$G_{n,m}=n\vec{b}_{1}+m\vec{b}_{2}$$
where if we consider that this is from a triangular lattice, the cartesian form of this vector will be $$G_{n,m}=\frac{2\pi}{a}\left(n,\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(2m-n\right)\right)$$
with $a$ being the lattice parameter.

My question is: is there a way that I can represent this vector by only one index such $G_{n,m}\rightarrow G_{k}$ without lost any information of the previous one?

Comment: You probably could with some suitable space-filling curve (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), then index will then be a vertex on the curve. But you would still have to cover 2d space. Anyway, what is the aim?

Comment: It's easy to do if you have a given, finite number of lattice sites in at least one direction. Is that the case, or do you have an infinite lattice?

Comment: Technically, yes, since there's a bijection $\mathbb{Z \times Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the numerical calculations from this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.2126.pdf), and so far I understand, the authors did this transformation $G_{n,m}\rightarrow G_{k}$ in some step,  but the way they did it was not clear for me.